# Using Java XMLSerialiser, how can I insert a string into a node

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xml-attribute

I am currently using xmlserialiser to output something like the following

```
<Node1>
   <Child2 attr1="abc">
   <Child3 attr2="xyz">
<Node1>
```

I have a string like this:

```
String stringAttribute = "testAttribute='testAttributeValue'";
```

is there a way using the xmlserialiser to insert the string into the nodes, e.g.

```
<Node1>
   <Child2 attr1="abc" testAttribute='testAttributeValue'>
   <Child3 attr2="xyz">
<Node1>
```

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Which `Xmlserializer` are you talking about? From [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xml/serialize/XMLSerializer.html)?

Comment: sorry, an obvious omission: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer